# What should happen to questions that are technically duplicates, but asker does not understand how their code fits into a general concept?

Tags: discussion

I feel like many users have seen marked duplicate questions, but do not understand how their code fits in with the larger concept. Especially for beginner programmers, it can be difficult to fit a general explanation of a concept into specific code.

Comment: You could always invite the user to a chat room where you can explain it to them.

Comment: I didn't even know chat rooms are a feature. How do you access them?

Comment: It's in the list of links at the bottom of the page, above the columns of links to other SE sites. It's also in the drop down menu when you click on the icon at the far right of the top bar. To the right of the link of Stack Overflow is "Help   Chat    Log Out".

Comment: All existing chat rooms: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/  There's an orange button at the bottom to create a new room. You can create one and invite the user to it to talk. IIRC, if you invite a user to a room you created, they can join regardless of their rep.

Comment: Adding comment explaining the connection is probably the best option (if you can fit explanation in comment)... Otherwise one-to-one tutoring in chat (make sure you can stand teaching - it is *hard*)

Comment: @BSMP no, they have to have 20 (15?) rep to talk in chat. we've run into that before.

Comment: @TinyGiant Ah, I did not in fact remember correctly. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: One of the easiest ways I have found is to go to a user's SO profile, and then prepend the url with `chat.` It will take you to their profile on chat and then from there you can create a room with the two of you

Comment: @mhodges Just tried it with you and got `chat.meta.stackoverflow.com uses an invalid security certificate.` - is it not supposed to work on meta?  (`chat.stackoverflow.com` works with no warnings) (I don't actually want to chat, you mentioned the feature so it was just convenient  =D)

Comment: @Izkata Yeah AFAIK it only works for stack overflow, not meta. I haven't tried any of the other exchange sites though

Comment: Not meaning to take things OT, but @BSMP, taking things to chat is really wrong. It's not only something newbies do not have access to, experienced answerers have no inclination (or experience) with. Maybe if SO made this feature more intuitive? Maybe more obvious? Or at least more user-friendly? The bottom line for me is chat is one of the least useful features of SO.

Comment: @dfd that's definitely needed for this feature to be useful. I literally couldn't find it.

Comment: That's (yet) another thing. The only way I found it was when commenting frequently/quickly enough (like in a chat) for some automatic bot to request I take it to chat. The one time I did, someone with 10x the rep points as me helped, but *after* I set things up because they had no experience either.

Comment: @dfd - Moving a conversation to chat is not "really wrong". In fact, as you just said, leaving too many comments on a question will result in a request to move a conversation to chat. It is in fact what you're supposed to do if you want to have an extended conversation. I already acknowledged I was wrong about the rep requirement when Tiny Giant corrected me.

Comment: @BSMP, apologies, I was "wrong" in my use or terms. :-) That said, the current way chat is set up - even after the hard work done on the redesign - it is a woefully underused feature here. One I will be critical of. (Enough of my hijacking. This MSO question has an answer I agree with.)

Comment: @TinyGiant Huh, that's weird. For some reason even when I had very low rep (like 6 on SO and 1 everywhere else) I think I was able to chat in some channels; did I run into some kind of chat bug? If you want this weekend (if you're active in SE chat) we can try to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the about page:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers.

Maybe Stack Overflow is the wrong place for asking Questions, if they don't understand the basic concept about the technology they use, and do not read the manual, some blogs and google to retrieve some understanding.

That said, if somebody has tried all that, and still can not find the enlightening, this person is free to ask a question about the specific part that is confusing.

This way sometimes we have great Questions:

[What's the difference between the Dependency Injection and Service Locator patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557781/whats-the-difference-between-the-dependency-injection-and-service-locator-patte)

So what should you do? Move on, life's to short.

Comment: I can well imagine many enthusiast programmers will understand the basics, read the manual, some books etc. I don't think we're talking about those 'gimme codez' questions where the askwer doesn't *care*. I've asked plenty of questions where I can't get my head round the concept, even though there's duplicates on SO. Asking here definitely helped.

Comment: @Pureferret hence the second part of my answer. If the question is aking for a specific confusing part, I am sure it it will not get closed a duplicate of a question, that does not answer the confusing part.

Comment: We might want to make that more clear when we mark it as a duplicate. I feel it might become fairly frustrating for people to have their questions marked when they don't really understand how it fits in.

Comment: Yeah, maybe we could encourage the seconds part in the close reason message. *This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question. [add more usefull hints here]*. My english is to bad to propose one @meyer9